# Extract drug class using rxcui code extracted from Rxnorm API

Tags: python, json

I wanted to extract drug class using Rxnorm API ([RxNorm API](https://lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/RxNav/APIs/RxNormAPIs.html)) using NDC code. My python codes are:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#pip install simplejson
import os
import sys
import requests
import simplejson as json

def connectionCheck():
    url = 'http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/version'
    header = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    getCheck = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    if getCheck.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        response = "RXNorm server response error. Response code: %s" % getCheck.status_code
    else:
        response = "Connection check complete. RXNorm online. Response code: %s" % getCheck.status_code
    return response

def rxNorm(ndc):
    # ndc value coming from master.py
    # ndc = [array of ndc values]
    if ndc[0] is None:
        return {"rxcui": "", "rxtty": "", "rxstring": ""}
    else:
        # if internet or request throws an error, print out to check connection and exit
        try:
            baseurl = 'http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/'

            # Searching RXNorm API, Search by identifier to find RxNorm concepts
            # http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui?idtype=NDC&id=0591-2234-10
            # Set url parameters for searching RXNorm for SETID
            ndcSearch = 'rxcui?idtype=NDC&id='

            # Search RXNorm API, Return all properties for a concept
            rxPropSearch = 'rxcui/'
            rxttySearch = '/property?propName=TTY'
            rxstringSearch = '/property?propName=RxNorm%20Name'

            # Request RXNorm API to return json
            header = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
            def getTTY(rxCUI):
                # Search RXNorm again using RXCUI to return RXTTY & RXSTRING
                getTTY = requests.get(baseurl+rxPropSearch+rxCUI+rxttySearch, headers=header)

                ttyJSON = json.loads(getTTY.text, encoding="utf-8")

                return ttyJSON['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][0]['propValue']

            def getSTRING(rxCUI):
                # Search RXNorm again using RXCUI to return RXTTY & RXSTRING
                getString = requests.get(baseurl+rxPropSearch+rxCUI+rxstringSearch, headers=header)
                stringJSON = json.loads(getString.text, encoding="utf-8")

                return stringJSON['propConceptGroup']['propConcept'][0]['propValue']

            # Search RXNorm using NDC code, return RXCUI id
            # ndc = [ndc1, ndc2, ... ]
            for item in ndc:
                getRXCUI = requests.get(baseurl+ndcSearch+item, headers=header)
                if getRXCUI.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
                    print ("RXNorm server response error. Response code: %s" % getRXCUI.status_code)
                rxcuiJSON = json.loads(getRXCUI.text, encoding="utf-8")
                # Check if first value in list returns a RXCUI, if not go to next value
                try:
                    if rxcuiJSON['idGroup']['rxnormId']:
                        rxCUI = rxcuiJSON['idGroup']['rxnormId'][0]
                        rxTTY = getTTY(rxCUI)
                        rxSTRING = getSTRING(rxCUI)
                        return {"rxcui": rxCUI, "rxtty": rxTTY, "rxstring": rxSTRING}
                except:
                    # if last item return null values
                    if item == ndc[-1]:
                        return {"rxcui": "", "rxtty": "", "rxstring": ""}
                    pass
        except:
            sys.exit("RXNorm connection")
```

Test using Toy NDC ID Code:

```
dataTest=rxNorm(['69238131109'])
print(dataTest)
```

which gave me the following output:

```
{'rxcui': '483448', 'rxtty': 'SCD', 'rxstring': 'pregabalin 50 MG Oral Capsule'}
```

Now I am interested to get the drug class using `'rxcui': '483448'` info using [RxClass API](https://lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/RxNav/APIs/api-RxClass.getClassByRxNormDrugId.html). However, I couldn't make sense of this API. How can I use `'rxcui': '483448'` info  here to get the desired drug class. I appreciate your time. Thanks!

Comment: Like this: https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxclass/class/byRxcui.json?rxcui=483448?

Comment: @Marat Yes, and from this file I am looking for "Anticonvulsant agent","classType":"THERAP" which is returned from snomed classUrl. I don't need the rest of the info from this file. I have like few thousands rxcui codes.

Comment: It is unclear why you have added the "pandas", "beautifulsoup" and "xml-parsing" tags.

Comment: @mzjn Since NDC code "69238131109"  is associated this XML file https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui?idtype=NDC&id=69238131109 to get the RxCui code.

Comment: I am not familiar with rxnav/rxnorm, but there is no mention of XML, Pandas or BeautifulSoup in the question.